# Is there a variable name that stores name of the stored procedure currently running?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is there a variable name that stores name of the stored procedure currently running? Something similar to $0 in Unix.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE my_sproc(
  param1 IN NUMBER,
  )
  AS      
  BEGIN
    exec other_sproc(XXX);
  END;
END;
```

XXX <- stores the string "my_sproc".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the Oracle version, you may be able to use conditional compilation and `$$PLSQL_UNIT`

If `other_sproc` just prints out the value passed in

```
create or replace procedure other_sproc( p_in in varchar2 )
as
begin
  dbms_output.put_line( p_in );
end;
/
```

then in Oracle 11g, you can use `$$PLSQL_UNIT` in the caller

```
SQL> create or replace procedure my_sproc
  2  as
  3  begin
  4    other_sproc( $$PLSQL_UNIT );
  5  end;
  6  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec my_sproc;
MY_SPROC

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

This doesn't work as well when you are using packages though (and your stored procedures should almost always be in packages) because the `$$PLSQL_UNIT` will be the package name not the procedure name.

Note as well that you do not use `EXEC` in a PL/SQL block.  `EXEC` is a SQL*Plus command.  You simply call `other_sproc` like I do here.